# System.arraycopy getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays

System.arraycopy getting ava.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException..  I am trying to copy data from one array to the next.  but I am getting a exception

```
private String array[] = { "NO DATA YET" };


 private void setListData()
    {
        String array2[] = { "Iphone", "Tutorials", "Gallery", "Android",    "item 1", "item 2", "item3", "item 4" };
        System.arraycopy(array2, 0, array, 0, array2.length);
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

You're trying to copy 8 items into an array of length 1. You can't do that.

From [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29):

> Otherwise, if any of the following is true, an IndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown and the destination is not modified:
>
> - The srcPos argument is negative.
> - The destPos argument is negative.
> - The length argument is negative.
> - srcPos+length is greater than src.length, the length of the source array.
> - destPos+length is greater than dest.length, the length of the destination array.

In this case, `destPos + length` is 8, and `dest.length` is 1, hence the exception is being thrown.

Note that arrays in Java have a fixed length. If you want an expandable container, look at `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thank you sir @Jon Skeet, for this documentation answer

Comment: The doc says, it will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, however, it threw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. That's what confused me, because in my algorithm, I cannot figure out, what was wrong, as it does not provide any details.

Comment: @Oliv: Well an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` *is* an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - it's a subclass. If you know which statement in your method is failing, you can add logging just before it for what your call is going to do - and then it should be obvious which parameter is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because the length of `array` is 1.

The declaration `array[] = { "NO DATA YET" };` creates an array of length 1 with one item in it.

Instead declare destination array as:

```
private String array[] = new String[8];
```

Answer (score 1):

array only has a length of 1 and you're trying to copy 8 things into it from array2.  Try using an ArrayList or something that will grow as you need it to grow.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION TO ALL TYPES OF ARRAYINDEXOUTOFBOUNDS EXCEPTION:**

Understand this with the help of following example facing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
    public static void main(String [] args){
         String dest[] = { "Iphone", "Tutorials", "Gallery", "Android",    "item 1", "item 2", "item3", "item 4" };
            String src[]=new String[8];
            System.arraycopy(src, 0, dest, 1, src.length);
            System.out.println(dest[4]);
    }
```

**Solution to this above case can be any of the following:**

**1.** Either increase the size of destination array so it could find a place.

**2.** Since we are starting from index 1 so you may copy only 7 elements from the source array.

**3.** Or you can start copying from index 0 in the destination array so it can accommodate all the array elements of source array.